# Authenticate Azure AD user on IIS hosted web site & web service

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-identity, claims-based-identity, adfs

We have an intranet based application, for simplicity let's say it's architecture is an IIS hosted Asp.net MVC 5 website that gets data from an IIS hosted web api 2 service on a different url solely via client side jQuery Ajax requests.

We now have a requirement for the site to be available via the internet. We use ADFS to authenticate a domain user on the website which works well, however the web api also requires authentication and here lies the problem - how to pass the ADFS authentication to the web service?

Comment: What authentication is it using currently (Integrated Windows Auth)? What version of ADFS are you using? Are web app and api service hosted on same domain?

Comment: Hi, yes internally we use Windows auth, I believe we have ADFS 2 but will confirm. The site and service will be on different domains as the service will be used by other apps.

Comment: Actually we use ADFS 3.0.

Comment: I'm a bit confused. Your title says Azure AD user. If you already have Azure AD federated with ADFS, all the samples that work with Azure AD will federate that auth with ADFS successfully.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to support internet access to your application is to authenticate against Azure AD and either sync your on-premise Active Directory to the cloud or federate the authentication back to your on-premise ADFS proxy. See [this video](https://channel9.msdn.com/Series/Azure-Active-Directory-Videos-Demos/Configuring-AD-FS-for-user-sign-in-with-Azure-AD-Connect) for more info.

Using Azure AD, you can use the OpenID Connect protocol to sign in your users to your web application and use OAuth 2 access tokens to secure your web api.

Microsoft has provided an example of this [here](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-webapi-openidconnect).

Comment: We're fine for the web app, the question is more related to how to also authenticate to the seperate web service.